# Replace numbers with boolean True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've got a dataframe with a column like this:

```
df['test'] = [NaN, 1.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 13.0]
```

I'd like to replace NaN with False and all the floats with True.

```
[False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

I tried:

```
df['test'].replace(np.nan, False, inplace=True)
df['test'].replace(np.float64, True, inplace=True)
```

**Problem: this replaces NaN correctly but not floats.**

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: kind of hacky, but fun: `df['test'] > -np.inf` or if your values are always positive `df['test'] > 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) method

```
df['test'].notna()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Not the best answer, but one of the ways.

```
>>> df
   test
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5  13.0
>>> df.apply(lambda x: pd.notna(x))
    test
0  False
1   True
2  False
3  False
4  False
5   True
>>>
```